# Value in cell, to reference a row on another worksheet in the workbook, to delete rows beneath

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use the last cell reference from column A of one of my worksheets as a basis to delete rows, that are beneath that number, from another worksheet in the same workbook.

I have the following VBA written as a message to delete rows that are that are beneath the total. I had to add 5 to the total count as the headers have a 5 row difference between them.

```vb
Dim lRow As Long

'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("EIB (w formula)").Select

MsgBox "Last row of LN load: " & lRow & vbNewLine & _
        "Delete all rows beneath A" & lRow + 5
```

Comment: `Sheets("EIB (w formula)").Rows(lRow + 5 & ":" & Rows.Count).Clear`?

Comment: Thanks a million- The code works! I'll break down each element of the code so I can better understand it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clear from `lrow + 5` down to the very last row:

```
With Sheets("EIB (w formula)")
   .Rows(lRow + 5 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Clear
End With
```